# Proving $\max\{f,g\}$, $\sum x_i^2$ and $e^{f(x)}$ are convex functions

Tags: proof-verification, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

> Verify if the functions below are convex.
>
> a) $f(x) = \max \{g(x),h(x)\}$ where $h$ and $g$ are convex.
>
> b) $t(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$
>
> c) $s(x) = e^{f(x)}$, $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$

a)

Suppose without loss of generality that $$\max\{g(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y), h(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)\} = g(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)$$

then

$$f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) = \max\{g(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y), h(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)\}=\\g(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \le \lambda g(x) + (1-\lambda) g(y) \le \lambda \max\{g(x),h(x)\} + (1-\lambda) \max\{g(y),h(y)\}=\\\lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y)$$

therefore $f$ is convex

b) $$t(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) = \sum_{i=1}^n(\lambda x_i + (1-\lambda) y_i)^2 \le \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda^2x_i^2 + (1-\lambda)^2 y_i^2\le^* \\\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda x_i^2 + (1-\lambda)y_i^2 = \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y)$$

- because $\lambda\in[0,1]$ so $\lambda^2 \le \lambda$

so this function is also convex

c) there are no assumptions about $f$ so I'm gonna consider the cases where it is convex and where it is not.

**If $f$ is convex:**

$$s(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) = e^{f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y)}\le e^{\lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y)} = e^{\lambda f(x)}e^{(1-\lambda)f(y)}$$

I don't think it is less than $\lambda e^{f(x)} + (1-\lambda) e^{f(y)}$. So let's try to find an example of convex function such that

$$e^{\lambda f(x)}e^{(1-\lambda)f(y)}> \lambda e^{f(x)} + (1-\lambda) e^{f(y)}$$

for some $\lambda$. If we pick $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$, $f(x) = |x|$, we must find $y$ such that

$$e^{\frac{1}{2} |x|}e^{\frac{1}{2}|y|}> \frac{1}{2} e^{|x|} + \frac{1}{2} e^{|y|}$$

for some $x$

I don't think there's a solution for this inequality, at least for this $\lambda$. I also tried $f(x)=x^2$ but coulnd't find anything.

**For arbitrary $f$** (not necessairly convex), we should search for an inequality

$$e^{f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y)}> \lambda e^{f(x)} + (1-\lambda)e^{f(y)}$$

pick $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$:
$$e^{f(\frac{1}{2} x + \frac{1}{2} y)}> \frac{1}{2} e^{f(x)} + \frac{1}{2}e^{f(y)}$$

lets pick $x=0,y=1$ and try to find some $f$ such that

$$e^{f(\frac{1}{2})}> \frac{1}{2} e^{f(0)} + \frac{1}{2}e^{f(1)}$$

I could define a picewise function that would make this not be valid but I'm focusing on continuous $f$. I'm also having a hard time finding a funcion that satisfies this. Maybe the function $e^{f(x)}$ is indeed convex for continuous $f$ but I didn't notice.

Comment: You can prove part (c) by taking logarithms on both sides and assuming $f(x)$ is convex? I am not sure how to prove (c) for any general function $f(x)$

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) looks okay.

(b) You can not say $$\sum_{i=1}^n(\lambda x_i + (1-\lambda) y_i)^2 \le \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda^2x_i^2 + (1-\lambda)^2 y_i^2$$ unless you're sure that $x_iy_i >0$ for all $i$. For this problem I'll give you a hint.

**HINT: Sum of convex functions is convex**

(c) In general it doesn't hold, unless $f(x)$ is convex [See here why](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244059/show-that-efx-is-convex). Counterexample let $n = 1$ and then the double derivative:
$$g'(x)= f'(x)e^{f(x)}$$
$$g''(x) = (f''(x) + [f'(x)]^2)e^{f(x)}$$
Choose $f(x) = \sin x$ then $f'(x) = \cos x$ and $f''(x) = -\sin x$ hence $$f''(x) + [f'(x)]^2 = -\sin x + \cos^2 x$$
At $x = 0$, $g''(x) > 0$ and at $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ we have $g''(x) <0$. Hence, the function could not be convex.

Answer (score 2):

a) quite OK.
b) Where do you have $2\lambda(1-\lambda)x_iy_i$? The convexity of a function in question follows directly by convexity of a quadratic function of one variable.
c) for convex $f$ this is a composition of an increasing convex function (exponential) and the convex one. So it is convex. If $f$ is nonconvex it is false. For example the Gauss function $e^{-x^2}$ is of course non-convex.

Comment: Can't I use $(a+b)^2 \le a^2 + b^2$? Then $\sum (a+b)^2 \le \sum a^2 + b^2$, if we pick $a = \lambda x_i$ and $b=(1-\lambda)y_i$ we should have what I've written

Comment: Put $a=b=1$. Is it true that $(a+b)^2\le a^2+b^2$?

Try to prove that $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, $f(x)=x^2$, is convex. Hint: show that $\lambda x^2+(1-\lambda)y^2-\bigl(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\bigr)^2\ge 0$ by an elementary algebra. The expression you should obtain by this algebra is $2\lambda(1-\lambda)(x-y)^2$.