# Are there any increasing concave functions that grow faster than $e^x$?

Tags: asymptotics, exponential-function

As titled. Intuitively I don't think there is any. But I wish to get a somehow rigorous argument, not even necessarily a proof. If anyone has any reference on this, it would also be much appreciated.

Comment: What about $e^{e^x}$ and so forth? Or $4^x$

Comment: Ummm... $x^{x^{x^x}}$?

Comment: Everyone be missing the concave condition?

Comment: @jlammy: the question was changed to convex...

Comment: Well I'll guess we have to wait for OP to clarify -- the question wasn't edited by them.

Comment: If the question is on concave functions, by definition of concavity any concave function $f$ is bounded above by $f(0)+(f(1)-f(0))x$ for all $x\ge1$. Therefore increasing concave functions are $O(x)$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @jlammy pretty sure OP was actually talking about convex functions since he mentioned $e^x$

Comment: @5201314 That's provided the OP knows the difference between convex and concave, and gives a damn. But this is MSE, so...

Comment: [If $f$ is convex, then $e^f$ is convex.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244059/show-that-efx-is-convex) See how to apply this to find infinitely many functions with faster and faster growth.

Comment: For some reason this question was edited from "concave" to "convex", it is now rolled back

Comment: @Gae.S. Could you please elaborate a little further on why this bound holds?

Comment: @Gae.S. I got it now. Your answer is basically what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\Gamma(x)$ (the factorial for non-integer values) is such a function. As is $2^{2^x}$ and $2$ to the power of the previous function and so on. Even $3^x$ grows faster than $e^x$ because its base is larger.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of examples of convex functions that grow faster than exponential functions. Some examples are:

- Double exponential function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_exponential_function
- Factorials / Gamma function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial
- Tetration https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head: $x^x$.