# Graphically solve the following inequality

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, soft-question, graphing-functions

Giving some math indications to my brother whom is in high school, I ran into the following:

Sketch $f(x)=\log_2(|x-1|+1)$ and using the graphic solve the following inequality:

$\sqrt{x}+ f(x) \geq 1$.

Now, the graphic is the following (thanks to Desmos):

[image: 'where the dotted curve is $\sqrt{x}$']

The problem to me is that at my brother level there is no knowledge of calculus, derivatives and so on, but only elementary (algebraic) properties of some functions,

> so how can one solve such a problem using the graphic without
>   calculus?

I mean for $x\geq 1$ it is evident, for $x< 0$ it is undefined, but for $0\leq x<1$ ?

Comment: Maybe, just plot $\sqrt{x}+f(x)$ and see if it is $\ge 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $\sqrt{x}\geq x$ for all $x\in[0,1],$ and $f(x)\geq 1-x$ for all $x\in[0,1].$ Then $$\sqrt{x}+f(x)\geq x+(1-x)=1\text{ for all }x\in[0,1].$$

Graphically, the two inequalities I used are just observing that these functions lie over the line segments connecting $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ (the first inequality) and connecting $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ (the second inequality), respectively.

Comment: Oh thank you!  This is absolutely a solution to the problem! Now I wonder if it is possible to solve $f(x)\geq 1-x$ in the interval without calculus, and this probably reduces to the fact that the exponential is convex, which i think can be done without calculus. E.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667300/proof-of-concavity-of-log-function